# AngularJS Input[type="number"] Validation allow only numbers to be entered

Tags: angularjs, validation, meteor

I have an input box asking for a number and what I'm trying to do is to make sure the user does not type any letter or any digit that is not valid.

This is my code so far:

```
    <form name="userForm" novalidate>
        Calories Needed : 
        <input type="number" min="0" ng-model="user.calories">
    </form>
```

I've been looking for a way using AngularJS but have had no luck. I've come across posts where they suggested creating a directive but I was looking for another technique. I'm still a beginner so I don't want to just use code w/o understanding what exactly is going on.

Comment: can use `ng-pattern` to set regex for fields ...see [input docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in luck I have a directive I use myself everywhere for this instance.

It's as easy as slapping **`<input valid-number />`** on an input. Voila!

```
angular.module('yourApp')
 .directive('validNumber', function () {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            // make sure we're connected to a model
            if (!ngModelCtrl) {
                return;
            }

            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (val) {
                // this is a test for whether it's undefined (from textbox)
                // or null when using type="number"
                if (val === undefined || val === null) {
                    val = '';
                }

                // here we try and clean it to make sure it's only numbers
                var clean = val.toString().replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '');

                // if a letter/etc got in there, set the model to the "cleaned" number value
                if (val !== clean) {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(clean);
                    ngModelCtrl.$render();
                }
                return clean;
            });

            // this is to test for "32" = SPACEBAR
            // and "101" = e (Chrome for some reason let's E go through in type="number"
            element.bind('keypress', function (e) {
                var code = e.keyCode || e.which;

                // Remove code === 101 part if you want 'e' to go through
                if (code === 101 || code === 32) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Is there any way around this other than using a directive? I'm still a beginner so I'm very hesitant to use something I might not completely understand. Thank you for your answer though!

Comment: @halapgos1 Well a directive is a custom html addition that in this case, does something beneficial for you. Simply add it within your app, and like I was showing on the html side, you only have to add the attribute `valid-number` and it'll do the rest for you!

Comment: `Chrome for some reason let's E go through in type="number"` This is due to the fact that Chrome allows numbers to be entered in scientific notation. `1.52e2` is a valid number (it is the same as typing out 152).

Comment: I know that, but at least that part can easily be taken out if someone wants that. For any projects I've ever worked on it's never been needed! @JoePontani

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS Sure, was just adding clarification if anyone wonders why `e` is allowed as a number :)

Comment: @JoePontani Added a comment in there to remove it if the person wants 'e'. Thanks Joe!

Comment: Thanks for giving an idea

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to read up on Angular's form validation- [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation)

It's as simple as adding "required" to your input, and 'novalidate' to the form element:

```
<form name="testForm" novalidate>
       <input type="number" required name="numberinput" class="form-control" ng-model="someNumber">
</form>
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/W2PV7OslMMtV97zS5oCg?p=preview)